# Передать в константу значение в зависимости от выбранного пользователем пункта

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного пользователем материала функция возвращала значение из файла.
Есть код:

```
double MainWindow::on_choose_clicked()
{
    QString func = ui->material->currentText(); //Передаём в константу выбранный пользователем материал
    QFile file("Materials.txt");
    QStringList strList;
    int n;
    if (func == "Медь")
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    else if (func == "Алюминий")
    {
        n = 2;
    }
    else //(func == "Железо")
    {
        n = 3;
    }
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        while(!file.atEnd())
        {
            strList << file.readLine();
        }
        strList[n];
    }
    file.close();

    return strList[n].toDouble();
}
```

Но он выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и есть ли способ реализовать это аккуратнее.
Сама ошибка:[image: Ошибка]
В файле записаны на данный момент три константы, каждая в свой строке. Кроме цифр в них ничего нет.

Comment: там же написано - *operator[] index out of range*

Comment: Да, но я впервые работаю с QFile и не понимаю, где у меня ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, основная проблема в том, что вы индексируете с единицы, тогда как в листе (как и во всех других контейнерах) индексация начинается с нуля. Проверьте в дебаггере, какой индекс вы пытаетесь взять и существует ли элемент с таким индексом в листе.

В целом же ваш код имеет несколько фундаментальных недостатков:

1. Вы привязываете материал к параметрам по строке;
2. Вы читаете список параметров материалов из файла при каждом изменении текущего материала;
3. Вы храните список материалов прибитым гвоздями в выпадающем списке, а параметры в файле. При этом изменение в файле потребует изменения интерфейса, увеличивая шанс посадить ошибку;

Как бы сделал я:

1. Вытащил бы название материала в файл, записывая пары значений название - параметр с каким-то разделителем, допустим, знаком табуляции;
2. Считал бы все пары один раз из файла при старте программы и заполнил выпадающий список;
3. При изменении текущего элемента выпадающего списка взял бы соответствующий элемент из справочника материалов (используя `ui->material->currentIndex()` и вытащил из него нужный параметр.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вся индексация в C++ и С идет, начиная с нуля. n = 1 и далее замените на n = 0.

Замечания:

2. Что делает строка strList[n] в конце блока if? Уберите мусор.
3. file.close(); поместить внутрь блок if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)), он ведь не должен выполняться, если файл не откроется.
4. добавьте после блока if блок else и в нем для ошибки открытия файла обработайте ошибку. Хотя бы выбросьте исключение throw Exception("Невозможно открыть файл").
5. strList << file.readLine(); лучше заменить на более читаемое append .